# How to exclude a single dependency in the build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

Say I have the following dependencies

```
+-A:1.0
  +-B:1.0
    +-C:1.0
```

I want to exclude dependency `B` and only `B` I want to keep all of its transitive dependencies so that in my classpath I will have both `A.jar` and `C.jar` but no `B.jar`.
I there an easy way to do so in sbt? For example, if I do

```
libraryDependencies += "com.example" % "A" % "1.0" exclude("com.example", "B")
```

It will not even try to resolve `C`

---

In other words, how do I only read the POM of `B`, skip downloading the jar and proceed normally with other dependencies?

Comment: May I ask why you want such behaviour?

Comment: Ah, I can't even explain, assume a weird license for B that says you have to bring binaries from somewhere else

Comment: I would remove it in "post processing" then (assembly ?)